# How to understand foo(char (&p)[10])?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(char (&p)[10]) {
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));
}

char p[10] = "aaa";

int main() {
    foo(p);
}
```

that code output `10`, but I can't understand.

What is the meaning of `char (&p)[10]` here?

Comment: It's `T&` where `T = char[10]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [C++ - Pass by Reference, Weird Thing for Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22742294/c-pass-by-reference-weird-thing-for-array)

Comment: You're guaranteeing that you're passing a `char[]` of size 10; this differs from passing a pointer and the size: `void foo(char* p, size_t n)`. If you print `sizeof(p)` in this case, you'll get the **size of a pointer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to the function `foo` is a reference (`&`) to a `char` array of 10 elements (`char ... [10]`). The name of the argument is `p`. Reference means that you specify the argument as-is (no pointer or address needed), so calling `foo(p)` in `main` is the correct way to do it given how `p` is declared. The function `foo` always prints 10 because its argument is 10 bytes in size.

Answer (score 2):

`foo()` is declared as a function that specifically gets a reference to a `char` array of size `10`, without any array-to-pointer conversions taking place.

Since `sizeof(char)` is 1, then `sizeof(char[10])` is 10. That's why your program prints 10.

Answer (score 0):

When the specifics of your application area call for an array of specific fixed size (array size is a compile-time constant), one of the ways to pass such an array to a function is by using a pointer-to-array parameter

```
void foo(char (*p)[10]);
```

in your case you have very similar situation but done by a reference:

```
void foo(char (&p)[10]);
```

That's all.